# dashboardSidebar : size of the page

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

[image]

Someone can help me  to resolve this display problem ?

Comment: can you please tell us what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I tried to get the box size to match the pivottable size and have a scroll bar if the size of the pivottable is more. But the background color, "skin-blue", doesn't seem to be fitting according to the size of the box.

Comment: Please include minimal reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

```
ui <-  dashboardPage(
  skin = "red",
  dashboardHeader(title = "TEXT MINING", disable = F),
  dashboardSidebar(
    tags$style(
      "text/css",
      ".navbar {background-color:bule;}",
      "html,body,#map  body {width:120%;height:100%}"
    ),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),

    tags$head(tags$style(
      ".wrapper {overflow: visible !important;}"
    )),

    selectInput("choix", h2("ALL vs PRIO"), c("ALL", "PRIO")),
    helpText("ALL= Tout les clients, PRIO= Clients séléctionés(Prioritaires)"),
    selectInput("w", h2("Pondération de la matrice "), c("Tf", "TfIdf")),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    helpText("Cliquer pour téléharger la table"),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    br()

  ),
  dashboardBody(mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    navbarPage(
      "",
      tabPanel("Données", icon = icon("database"), dataTableOutput('donnees')),
      tabPanel(
        "Analyses exploratoires",
        icon = icon("bar-chart"),

        box(
          title = "Les pages visitées",
          status = "warning",
          width = 25,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          plotOutput("pages", height = "650px")
        ),

        box(
          title = "Histogramme des notations ",
          status = "warning",
          width = 25,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          plotOutput("his", height = "650px")
        ),

        box(
          title = "score par nombre d'étoile",
          status = "warning",
          width = 25,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          plotOutput("sc", height = "650px")
        ) ,

        box(
          title = "Mots fréquents",
          status = "warning",
          width = 25,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          plotOutput("mots", height = "650px")
        )



      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Nuages et assosciations des mots ",
        icon = icon("cloud"),
        fluidRow(column(12, wellPanel(
          sliderInput(
            "max",
            "Nombre maximal de mots",
            min = 100,
            max = 300,
            value = 200,
            step = 10
          )
        )),
        column(
          12,

          box(
            title = "Word Cloud",
            status = "warning",
            width = 18,
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            collapsible = TRUE,
            plotOutput("nuage", height = "450px")
          )
        )),
        fluidRow(column(12, wellPanel(
          sliderInput(
            "lowf",
            "Choisir n tel que Fréquence(mots)>n",
            min = 5,
            max = 30,
            value = 10,
            step = 1
          )
        )),
        column(
          12,
          box(
            title = "Graphe des associations",
            status = "warning",
            width = 18,
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            collapsible = T,
            plotOutput("asso", height = "650px")
          )
        ))
      ),
      tabPanel("Clustering", icon = icon("sitemap"), fluidRow(column(
        12,
        box(
          title = "K-means",
          status = "warning",
          width = 30,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          plotOutput("cl", height = "650px")
        )
      ),
      column(
        12,
        box(
          title = "CAH",
          status = "warning",
          width = 30,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          plotOutput("cl2", height = "650px")
        )
      ))),
      tabPanel(
        "Rapport",
        icon = icon("book") ,
        tags$iframe(style = "height:800px; width:100%; scrolling=yes",
                    src =
                      "rapportTextMining.pdf")
      )
    )
  ))))
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what layout you are using. If you are using Column based layout for your boxes, then you can set the `box(width=NULL)`. That should fix the issue. From you code it looks like you are using column based layout. `width =25` does not make sense. Since, the overall width of the are is 12. So, set it to `width = NULL`, it will fix the issue. 
If you are using row based layout that is when you mess with the width parameters.